# unrecognized expression: [object Object].class :jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu on my site it just happens when I click on the flesh 
but I want if I click on the menu title the drop-down menu
I move the class nothing happens
I then try to do the work with jquery but in the first click all the menu scrolls but the second time i is displayed an error

This my html :

```
<ul id="responsive-menu" class="">
    <li id="responsive-menu-item-20419" class=" responsive-menu-item-current-ancestor">
        <a href="http://HappyHelps.com/conseils-bac-de-francais/" class="responsive-menu-item-link">Commence ici !</a>
    </li>
    <li id="responsive-menu-item-6434" class="responsive-menu-item-current-ancestor">
        <a class="responsive-menu-item-link">Méthode
        <div class="responsive-menu-subarrow">▼</div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <ul class="responsive-menu-submenu responsive-menu-submenu-depth-1">
        <li id="responsive-menu-item-19480" class=" responsive-menu-item-current-ancestor">
            <a href="http://HappyHelps.com/bac-de-francais-ecrit/" class="responsive-menu-item-link">Écrit
            <div class="responsive-menu-subarrow">▼</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

and this my js:

```
jQuery('.responsive-menu-item-link').click(function(){
     var clicked = jQuery(this);
    jQuery( clicked +".responsive-menu-subarrow").trigger( "click" );
 });
```

and this the erroe that I get :

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [objectObject].responsive-menu-subarrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should use `jQuery` codes like below:

```
jQuery('.responsive-menu-item-link').click(function(){
    var clicked = jQuery(this);
    jQuery( clicked ).find(".responsive-menu-subarrow").trigger( "click" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `clicked` is not an object so that `.trigger()` function falls into error.

Try this:

```
jQuery('.responsive-menu-item-link').click(function(){
     var clicked = jQuery(this);
    jQuery(clicked).find(".responsive-menu-subarrow").trigger( "click" );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `var clicked = jQuery(this);` will return the DOM Element Object of `.responsive-menu-item-link` which make sense

try with `jQuery(".responsive-menu-item-link .responsive-menu-subarrow").trigger( "click" );`